# Modifying comparator in quicksort

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

Quicksort on an integer array works by recursively partitioning halves of an entire array-- and in doing so, sorts the array. I understand the partitioning takes O(n), and because it's done recursively on each half (logN times), the total cost comes out to O(NlogN).

In Cracking the Coding Interview 6th edition, problem 10.2 asks to write a method to sort an array of strings so that all anagrams are next to each other. The author proposes two different solutions-- one of them is quicksorting the entire array, and as a result the anagrams would end up next to each other.

But--she says this is time O(NlogN). This is where I'm lost. For an integer array, the quicksort must visit each element and swap integers depending on if one is bigger than the other. This is O(1) cost per each N elements, summing up to O(N). However, the comparison for two strings that the author suggests breaks both strings into a char Array, sorts them, and then compares them. That process would be O(L logL) per string (where L is the length of the string) .. so it's O(LlogL) cost per N strings-- isn't that O(NlogN(L LogL))? Might be getting lost in the numbers, but it'd be very helpful if someone could explain to me how the author's process has O(NlogN) complexity for string comparisons. Below is her code:

```
class AnagramComparator implements Comparator <String> {
  public String sortChars(String s) {
    char[] content = s.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(content)
    return new String(content);
  }
  public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
    return sortChars(s1).compareTo(sortChars(s2));
  }
}
```

Comment: There are two _different_ `N`s here that you're conflating: the length of the strings and the number of strings.

Comment: Just to correct a misimpression: Quicksort does not necessarily partition the array in halves.  It partitions the array into two parts, but in the worst case, the first part (or second part) could consist of just one element.  In the worst case, this will happen every time the algorithm recurses, which is why Quicksort's worst case time is O(n^2) and not O(n log n).  The _average_ time is O(n log n), though.

Comment: @LouisWasserman you're absolutely right-- added edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The author may be assuming that the maximum length of a string is some constant, so that string comparisons are still O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edited question, you're right--each comparison will take O(L log L) time where L is the maximum string length.  Depending on how large the maximum string length is, this can multiply the sort time by a pretty significant factor.  Since sorting the characters in each string will be done multiple times, this appears to be an inefficient way to handle it.

A better way might be to define a new object:

```
public class AnagramSortElement implements Comparable<AnagramSortElement> {
    private String sourceString;
    private String sortedChars;
    // getters, constructors as needed
    // compareTo that compares sortedChars
}
```

so that you only compute `sortedChars` once for each input string.  You'd start out by creating a new `AnagramSortElement[]` array from the original `String[]`, and use that array for your sort.  This process will take O(N * (L log L)) instead of O((N log N) * (L log L)).  Then, when you're performing the sort, the comparisons will be much quicker since you've already sorted the characters; the sort would take O(N log N) on average.

It seems like this should be faster, but you'd have to profile it to make sure.  For very large N such that creating N new objects would put a strain on memory resources, and for rather small L, the original code could be faster.